# How to repeat the fragments (like a loop)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

i am developing an app which has a few fragments and i have set them up using an adapter which extends fragmentpager adapter, and i want the fragments to repeat when any of the end is reached. for e.g if i have set up 4 fragments and then when the user reaches the 4th fragment ,instead of blocking the view,the view should shift to the first fragment ...
i have been able to set up the fragments but don't know how to achieve this loop thing...

here is the code for the adapter

```
package sourcecode.jazzplayer;

import java.util.List; 

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    private static String[] titles = new String[] {"Songs", "My Playlists", "Artists","Albums"};

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle( int position )
    {
        return titles[ position ];
    }
}
```

and here is the code how i have set up the fragments

```
package sourcecode.jazzplayer;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import sourcecode.jazzplayer.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MyMusic  extends FragmentActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mymusic);


           List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentSongs.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentArtists.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentPlaylists.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentAlbums.class.getName())); 


            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);


            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);



            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
            pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

            pager.setCurrentItem(0);




    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Infinite Viewpager](https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager) project on Github.

Comment: thanx but it will screw things for me,i will have to change my entire code because  i am using FragmentPagerAdapter and here ViewPager has been used

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple with a [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html):

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position % 4);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position % 4;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

And when initializing the ViewPager set the initial page to a very high value, so you can move the pages both ways. For 4 pages, 0x40000000 is roughly half of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and is divisible by 4 (`id` is 0).

Comment: Wouldn't this also work if you just returned 4 from getCount(), because of the % in getItem()?

Comment: @Peter That's is the normal way and it wont repeat. The position you get on the other methods is always between 0 and getCount(). On the first page you won't be able to swipe to the right and on the last page you won't be able to swipe further left. That's why the initial page is important with this trick.

Answer (score 0):

I just pushed my recent code to GitHub [LoopingViewPager](https://github.com/imbryk/LoopingViewPager), I hope this will help you.

This ViewPager can work with views and with fragments, only small code modifications are needed in your adapter and xml files.